# ReportViewer cutting off top of report when zoomed

Tags: c#, asp.net

We have a report running out of SQL Server REporting Services that works fine. When zoomed to 150% it looks correct. (Seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/QB3Lb.png)

I built a asp.net page to display the report using ReportViwer. It displays the report fine and everything works (Seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/kS4sr.png)

The problem is you can't zoom in. It zooms in weird and cuts off the top of the page (Seen here https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3mY2.png).

Here is the reportviewer code in the aspx page.

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" ProcessingMode="Remote" SizeToReportContent="True"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Here is the back end C# code

```
void RenderReport()
        {
            //string SiteName = GetCurrentSiteNameFromSiteID((int)Session["SiteID"]);
            int SiteID = (int)Session["SiteID"];
            Uri ReportURI = new Uri(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ReportServerURI"]);
            ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = ReportURI;
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = @"/Calendarized Utility Report/Calendarized Utility Report";
            ReportParameter rpsite = new ReportParameter("siteid", SiteID.ToString());
            rpsite.Visible = false;
            ReportParameter rpyear = new ReportParameter("Year", year); //SiteID.ToString());
            rpyear.Visible = false;
            ReportParameter rpmonth = new ReportParameter("Month", month); //siteid", SiteID.ToString());
            rpmonth.Visible = false;


            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(rpsite);
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(rpyear);
            ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(rpmonth);

        }
```

Is there a parameter I am missing to allow me to zoom in correctly? I'm not using any css or anything.

Thanks

Edit: Both are using Report Viewer 2012, Version=11.0.3000.0 of Microsoft Reporting and viewing the site in IE 10. It works fine in Chrome.

Comment: What is the version of reportviewer and which browser are u using?

Comment: Sorry about that. I updated my question. Both are using Report Viewer 2012, Version=11.0.3000.0 of Microsoft Reporting and viewing the site in IE 10. It works fine in Chrome.

Comment: It could be compatibility issue. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee960138.aspx they only added support for IE9 in version 2012. Have you tried compatibility mode?

Comment: It's funny to ask after 5 years passed from your question, but did you manage to fix this? I'm having the same issue running IE 11. 10x

Comment: We never got it to work, we just built the report using HTML inside the page and removed report Viewer.